# Using curl to POST obtains a different response than when using requests to POST

Tags: python, curl

I am new to python programming and I have reached an impasse that I can't seem to solve. I am trying to use python requests module to to POST a request to a service in IBM Bluemix. It works fine when I use cURL to make the request but when I try to the requests module I get an error message. Since I am using the same data file, I am confused about why I am getting different results. Can anyone enlighten me?

Here is the code with access keys and URL modified as well as the what I think is the relevant part of the response:
Here is the cURL:

```
curl -i -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST \
  "https://ibm.Someservice.ibmcloud.com:9999/Action/modelName?accesskey=XXXXYYYYYZZZZZ+++++etc"  \
  --data-binary @sample-data.json
```

Here is the request code:

```
import requests
import json

def post2ndRequest():
    url = 'https://ibm.Someservice.ibmcloud.com:9999/Action/modelName?accesskey=XXXXYYYYYZZZZZ+++++etc'
    files = {'file': open('sample-data.json', 'rb')}
    headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
    print(r.text)
    return r.text

temp = 'PMresponseX.txt'
F = open (temp,'wb')
F.write(post2ndRequest())  
F.close()
```

And here is a chunk of the returned response:

```
<body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException:
Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit
(0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value</h1><HR size="1"
noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b>
<u>org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-'
(code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus
sign, for valid numeric value</u></p><b>description</b> <u>The server
encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this
request.</u></p>
```

It seems to be some sort of parsing error in the server yet the cURL works fine so the server side seems ok,... I have used the request module successfully before but not using https nor attaching an access key to the URL. Could that be the issue?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Full HTTP dumps from the both requests would help. Use a tool like Wireshark to record dumps and then compare what's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `--data-binary` option to `curl`, which according to the man page:

```
This  posts data exactly as specified with no extra pro‐ cessing
whatsoever.
```

Whereas in your call to `requests.post` you are using the `files` parameter, which according to the documentation:

```
:param files: (optional) Dictionary of ``'name': file-like-objects``
 (or ``{'name': ('filename', fileobj)}``) for multipart encoding upload.
```

It seems like you actually want to use the `data` parameter:

```
:param data: (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object
to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
```

Your current code is sending a multipart MIME archive where the server is expecting something completely different.

Comment: Thanks Larsks. I read the file into a variable which I passed into the request as data and sure enough, it worked. I thought I had already tried that but I must have been confusing it with another project. So that's great. Problem solved. Thanks again.